# why is my javascript intersection observer not working, no errors found in console, my javascript code below;

Tags: javascript, html, css, intersection-observer

I checked the variable names and each function I checked HTML tags I checked css positioning and everything is perfect but still not working please guys help me check if there's any error I  can't find, I tried console logging the forEach code and it's not working (I created a div with the class of bubble, i want the div to have the same backgroundcolor as the active section and it should also be imposed on the active nav item. I.e. if home section is active the home nav item should be the same backgroundcolor as the home section).
I have edited the question and added the HTML and CSS codes for better understanding.

```js
// variable names
const sections = document.querySelectorAll('section');
const bubble = document.querySelector('.bubble');
const gradient = [
  'linear-gradient(to right top, #ffb88c, #de6262)',
  'linear-gradient(to right top, #a73737, #7a2828)',
  'linear-gradient(to right top, #ed4264, #ffedbc)',
];

//options
let options = {
  threshold: 0.3,
  rootMargin: '0px',
  root: null,
};

// observer function
let observer = new IntersectionObserver(navCheck, options);

// navCheck function
function navCheck(scrolls) {
  scrolls.forEach((scroll) => {
    const classId = scroll.target.className;
    const activeAnchor = document.querySelector(`[data-page=${classId}]`);
    const gradientIndex = parseInt(scroll.target.getAttribute('data-index'));
    const coords = activeAnchor.getBoundingClientRect();
    const directions = {
      height: coords.height,
      top: coords.top,
      width: coords.width,
      left: coords.left,
    };
    if (scroll.isIntersecting) {
      bubble.style.background = gradient[gradientIndex];
      bubble.style.setProperty('left', `${directions.left}px`);
      bubble.style.setProperty('top', `${directions.top}px`);
      bubble.style.setProperty('width', `${directions.width}px`);
      bubble.style.setProperty('height', `${directions.height}px`);
    }
  });
}

sections.forEach((section) => {
  observer.observe(section);
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

header {
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 10px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  position: sticky;
  top: 0px;
  background-color: #fff;
}

nav {
  min-height: 10vh;
  margin: auto;
  width: 90%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

nav ul,
nav h1 {
  font-size 1.5rem;
  flex: 1;
}

nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

nav a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav ul div. bubble {
  position: absolute;
  /* border: 2px solid #ffb88c; */
  z-index: -1;
  background: linear-gradient(to right top, #ffb88c, #de6262);
  transform: scale(2);
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

section {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

section h2 {
  font-size 5rem;
  color: white;
}

.home {
  background: linear-gradient(to right top, #ffb88c, #de6262);
}

.about-us {
  background: linear-gradient(to right top, #a73737, #7a2828);
}

.contact-page {
  background: linear-gradient(to right top, #ed4264, #ffedbc);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="newproject.css" />
  <!-- <script src="projectjs.js"></script> -->
  <script src="gpt.js"></script>
  <title>lbl</title>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <nav>
      <h1 class="page-name">Lips By Lams</h1>
      <ul>
        <li><a data-page="home" href="#home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a data-page="about-us" href="#about-us">About Us</a></li>
        <li>
          <a data-page="contact-page" href="#contact-us">Contact 
        Page</a>
        </li>
        <div class="bubble"></div>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <main>
    <section id="home" data-index="0" class="home">
      <h2>home page</h2>
    </section>
    <section id="about-us" data-index="1" class="about-us">
      <h2>about us</h2>
    </section>
    <section id="contact-us" data-index="2" class="contact-page">
      <h2>contact page</h2>
    </section>
  </main>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please provide a full example we can run and test in a snippet.  This should include any HTML and CSS that goes along with it.  just the code alone without context is difficult to debug.

Comment: What are you expecting to happen that isn't happening? Just saying it isn't working doesn't really provide any clarity .

Comment: Ok I understand that saying it's not working doesn't really say what I want it to do, what I want it to do is change the background color of the active navigation item to match the active section. i.e. when user is on home section the nav item of home should have same background color

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Now, on this site, the dov changes background-color to match with the active section, but it doesn't cover the active nav item